# Custom objects classifier always returns one of classes even if the picture belongs to none of them

Tags: java, machine-learning, data-science, image-classification

My fruit detection app shows fruit results even though the user uploads a picture that is not a fruit. Is it possible to display a "no plant detected" message?

My code:

```
private void classifyImage(Bitmap image) {
    try {
        FruitDisease model = FruitDisease.newInstance(getApplicationContext());

        TensorBuffer inputFeature = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 224, 224, 3}, DataType.FLOAT32);
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * imageSize * imageSize * 3);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        int[] intValue = new int[imageSize * imageSize];
        image.getPixels(intValue, 0, image.getWidth(), 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

        int pixel = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < imageSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < imageSize; j++) {
                int val = intValue[pixel++];
                byteBuffer.putFloat(((val >> 16) & 0xFF) * (1.f / 255.f));
                byteBuffer.putFloat(((val >> 8) & 0xFF) * (1.f / 255.f));
                byteBuffer.putFloat((val & 0xFF) * (1.f / 255.f));
            }
        }
        inputFeature.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);

        FruitDisease.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature);
        TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();

        float[] confidences = outputFeature0.getFloatArray();
        int maxPos = 0;
        float maxConfidence = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < confidences.length; i++) {
            if (confidences[i] > maxConfidence) {
                maxConfidence = confidences[i];
                maxPos = i;
            }
        }

        String[] classes = {"Watermelon Healthy", "Watermelon Blossom End Rot", "Watermelon Anthracnose",
                "Mango Healthy", "Mango Bacterial Canker", "Mango Anthracnose",
                "Orange Scab", "Orange Healthy",
                "Orange Bacterial Citrus Canker", "Banana Healthy", "Banana Crown Rot",
                "Banana Anthracnose", "Apple Scab", "Apple Healthy", "Apple Black Rot Canker"};

        result.setText(classes[maxPos]);
        String s = "";
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
            s += String.format("%s: %.1f%%\n", classes[i], confidences[i] * 100);
            confidence.setText(s);
            confidence.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Comment: You didn't provide any context as to the dataset and how your model was trained. The classes suggest the model is trained on specific fruit and features found in the fruit, but it's not trained to determine "is_fruit, is_not_fruit". You probably need to inference the image against an object classifier model so it knows what fruit is, then pass the image frame to your existing model if the image is in fact fruit.

Comment: Differentiate between the classification logic and the UI-related code. Your question was about classification itself, not smth related to display - I cut irrelevant code from the question. But the remaining method is also a subject for refactoring. Isolate the classification code from the controls and edit the post to include only the classification-related method. It's best coding practices and shall pay off. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem splits into 2 different problems:

1. **Binary classification**: if the image depicts a fruit. Results: fruit/not fruit
2. **Multi-class classification**: which fruit is it?

Currently, you solve only a 2nd part. But there is no class 'not fruit at all'.  You can have N+1 class: N fruits and 1 not-a-fruit image class. But then it is going to be imbalanced which is a complication. Therefore, I suggest 2-step approach.

Comment: i want to add a function that return the result "unkown" if the probability for all class is less than the threshold you defined. The problem is i dont know how to implement that in my codes

Comment: So first you implement a model that knows only 2 classes: fruit and not fruit.
Then for items classified as fruits you run a second (independent model) that answers which particular fruit it is.

Make sure you isolate code with business logic from the UI code. Decoupling layers will allow you to combine model outcomes in any fashion when a product starts growing.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Well, I guess, you have a lot to read first. SO is not a place to put the whole course of programming in the comments. Try to google keywords and formulate your question as narrowly as possible. Otherwise, it's unclear what exactly you don't understand and the community won't write the whole app for you.